# Can I have validators inside validators with fluent validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

c# Pseudo-code

If I have a class

```
class Person
{
  string Name
  date DOB
  Address address
}
```

I can make a PersonValidator to validate Person

but since Address is a complex type, and sometimes I want to validate it separately, I have a PersonValidator and an AddressValidator. Question is, how do I use my AddressValidator inside my PersonValidator?

```
class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
   PersonValidator()
   {
       RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotEmpty();

       var addressValidator = new AddressValidator();
       addressValidator.Validate( person.address ) // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can invoke the `.SetValidator(IValidator)` method.

```
class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
   PersonValidator()
   {
       // CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

       RuleFor(c => c.Name)
           .NotEmpty().WithErrorCode("name_required");

       // Checks that the IEnumerable<Address> has at least 1 item
       RuleFor(c => c.Address)
           .NotEmpty().WithErrorCode("addresses_required");

       RuleForEach(c => c.Address)
           .SetValidator(new AddressValidator());

    }
}

class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
{
   AddressValidator()
   {
       // CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue;

       RuleFor(c => c.Postcode)
           .NotEmpty().WithErrorCode("postcode_required");
   }
}
```

Comment: Just figured this out myself as well, changed the accepted answer. Also there is a depricated `SetCollectionValidator` for the other problem I mentioned in the comment of the other answer where my addresses are actually a collection, which says to use `RuleForEach(c => c.Addresses).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());`

Comment: Thanks. From a unit test POV, there is also `_personValidator.ShouldHaveChildValidator(x => x.Address, typeof(AddressValidator));` that caters for that use case

Answer (score 2):

You can override validate method:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context) {
    var baseResult = base.Validate(context);
    var result = new AddressValidator().Validate(new ValidationContext<Address>(context.InstanceToValidate.Address);
    return new ValidationResult(baseResult.Errors.Concat(result.Errors));
}
```

Do this for async method variation as well.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I do have one problem though, in my use case, I have realised that the address is actually an array of addresses. I understand there's RuleForEach but I am not sure if there's a way to use the code in your example to handle each one, short of putting it into a loop. Any ideas?

Comment: From the top of my head I would just make it a loop.